# Flash: custom Loader flickers when mouse moves

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, loader

Disclaimer: I'm new to ActionScript 3.

I have a Main class (which extends Sprite) that adds my Loader as a child. The Loader processes a continuous stream of images from a server (think MJPEG). I create a socket, add a ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA listener, and put the data into a local buffer. If I have a complete frame, then I call loadBytes() on it, and go back to waiting for the next chunk of data to arrive.

This works very well. However, if the mouse is moving when the image is being updated, then the control flickers slightly. But if no frames are being received, then there is no flickering. Do I need to double-buffer the image? If so, where do I do this? The Loader doesn't seem like the right place.

Comment: interesting.  is the mouse moving over the loader or just moving, maybe even outside of the window?  have you tried setting `myLoader.mouseEnabled = false;`?  that might only be a band-aid solution but on the other hand, MOUSE_MOVE mouse events can be pretty heavy, especially on mobile.

Comment: Hi, thanks for chiming in. That did it! Why don't you post it as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see comment above:

```
myLoader.mouseEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

That alone does not work.
I have been hunting for what seems like hours and I found the answer by browsing the documentation for Loader.

You need this:

```
myLoader.mouseEnabled = false;
myLoader.cacheAsBitmap = true;
```

This speeds up rendering and the flashing goes away.